# Is it okay for two or more interfaces to have the same methods?

Tags: java, oop, interface

I'm making a simple game with Java, and I have this doubt.

Suppose that there's an interface for every game character

```java
public interface Entity{
   Vector2 getPosition();
   /* More methods...*/
}
```

Then I want to create an interface called Automata implemented by every class that uses AI stuff (This could be a special case of Entity, but I thought it separately because of reusability)

```java
public interface Automata{
  Vector2 getPosition(); // The AI stuff needs to know this
  /* More methods needed for AI (some may also be the same as Entity)... */
}
```

I think this promotes modularity, because every interfaces describes its methods without worrying about the existence of other interfaces, but while I was writing this I felt like I was repeating myself, so is having this two (or may be more) interfaces with same methods something bad ?

Comment: This depends on the semantics, if the two methods are supposed to have the same meaning, you could define it in a third interface that is extended by the other two.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there is something common between both interfaces then maybe you can define a parent interface and then `Entity` and `Automata` could extend it.

Let me illustrate it below :

```
interface AI {
    Vector2 getPosition();
}

interface Entity extends AI { }
interface Automata extends AI { }
```

This way any other interface that is a part of AI would not need to explicitly add another method but instead just extend `AI`